# OnPreferenceChangeListener in Different Process - Sharing Preference Data

Tags: android, process, callback, preferences, sharedpreferences

So my problem is as follows:  I have 2 services running in different processes and would like to keep it this way.  One is busing data from databases to bound applications and the second is polling for incoming data through sockets.  I feel keeping these in independent process would be better.  The problem is that I would like to have a shared preferences between the two services and would like to implement OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener to update setting needed for polling and busing data.  I can't implement OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener in the services since they run on different processes.  I could implement this on the PreferenceActivity but how do I communicate to the services for immediate update?  I do not want to use AIDL and worry about binding.  There is the possibility of creating broadcast receivers and sending out intents but these seems like a big work around if the settings menu grows.  Any other great ideas out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a simple SharedPreferences based on ContentProvider, which can be used accross processes, you can find them from my bitbucket https://bitbucket.org/ABitNo/zi/src/783b6b451ba1/src/me/abitno/zi/provider/preference

Comment: Tends to be broken link. (will upvote again if you will fix it :-) )

Answer (score 1):

all right here is your answer...

for the preference of this example lets take 3 classes - 2 services service A and B (href A,B) and Settings(preferenceActivity)

initialize the two services as

```
public class ServiceA/B extends serice implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{
    @Overside
    public void onCreate(....){
        Settings.getPrefs(this).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);  

     }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Settings.getPrefs(this).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);  
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Unregister the listener whenever a key changes
        Settings.getPrefs(this)
                .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        String key) {
    System.out.println("++"+key+"++");
    if(key == "KEYA"||key == "KEYC")
        Do_what_ever_you_want();
            if (key == "KEYB")
        do_anything();
    }
    do_anything(){}
    Do_what_ever_you_want();
}
```

Shared preference Part.

```
public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity implements
OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{
      public static final String PREFS_PRIVATE = "PREFS_PRIVATE";
      public static final String MASTERKEY = "!@#$%^&*";

      public static final String KEYA = "KEYA";
      public static final String KEYB = "KEYB";
      public static final String KEYC = "KEYC";

       --- the create and get methods for getting and sharing data in the prefs... ..... 
      // get them from just a google search.

}
```

I have this system implemented in one of my applicaiton... and deployed... so fiddle around these basics and let me know how it is goes...

Rajesh...

Comment: This does not answer my question.  This answer assumed the Service is running in the same process as the PreferenceActivity.  That is why the OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener works.  In my application this solution will not work because the service run in different process as defined by the Manifest file 'android:process=""'.  If I put everything in one process this will work - I have tested that.  But this will not work for my application.

Comment: did you try it... i wrote it in my app... I know what a service means and this one is no way inside anything... it can be invoked from the manifest... or a broadcastlistener...

Comment: I believe that you did it.  However listeners will not work if running in another process.  You have your service and application in the same process.  Mine works if I do that, but the second I define my service to run in a new process it does not work.  However I solved the problem so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Iinteresting very interesting. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: sorry I will explain the answer. it wouldn't let me answer my question within 8 hours.